# Selecting only relevant lines in a file and deleting all others. Repeat for all files in a folder

Tags: perl

I have some files in a folder, and I would like to perform following operation on each file of this folder.

Each file has lots of data lines. The values are numbers separated by colons `:`. Only the first value of each line matching a set of values (I have about 20 numbers) should be present in the files and rest of the lines should be deleted.

Please let me know how to do this in Perl?

Sample line shown below from file:

```
100:0:5000:0:0:0:1:97 :
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a script to do this on just one file? Or even just to find lines which match in a single file?

Comment: Please show what you have written so far and describe what problems you are having

Comment: I haven't tired yet.. I am new to Perl..In the meanwhile i am writing but might take sometime...

Answer (score 3):

- [`Open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file
- [`Read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) each line
- Check whether it is required in the output, using either a [`regular expression`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) or a [`hash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) as appropriate
- [`Print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) the line if necessary
- Keep track of which values have already been output using a [`hash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to at least learn some Perl, so you can at least understand whatever answer you get.  You're getting downvoted because you don't have any proficiency in the language you're requesting help in.

Fortunately, this is a rather easy thing to do in Perl, and if you use the [Llama Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do), you can learn what you need in a few hours. The Llama book is an excellent resource for anyone wanting to learn Perl.